# Close NSWindow but do not nil it

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have a window-less app with the "Application is agent" set to YES. In that app I have a "let mainWindow: NSWindow" and with the click on a menu item I do the following:

```
func createNewWindow(){
    mainWindow.center()
    mainWindow.hidesOnDeactivate = true
    mainWindow.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
    mainWindow.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 1, alpha: 0.4)
    mainWindow.contentViewController = searchView
    mainWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
}
```

If I click outside my window or in any way shift focus to another app, my window closes and I have to click my menu item to open it again. Now this is what I want, so this is great. But if I in the view controller call "self.view.window?.close()" and there after click my menu item to open my window again, I get a bad access when accessing mainWindow, so I am guessing something has set it to nil when I close it.

How do I close my window in the same way as when I click outside the window? Or how do I otherwise prevent the bad access error?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not *something*, **you** set it to `nil` when you close the window.

From the [documentation of `close()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419662-close)

> If the window is set to be released when closed, a release message is
>   sent to the object after the current event is completed. For an
>   `NSWindow` object, the default is to be released on closing, while for
>   an `NSPanel` object, the default is not to be released. You can use the
>   `isReleasedWhenClosed` property to change the default behavior.

Either change the behavior or call `orderOut(_:)` which doesn't release the window.